# How to use multi-threading to make my application faster

Tags: java, multithreading, list, concurrency, hashset

I am iterating through a List of Strings with +- 1500 entries. In each iteration I am again iterating through a List of Strings, but this time with +- 35 million entries. The result of the application is perfect. But it takes the application a long time (2+ hours) to give me the result. How should I structure multithreading to make my application faster?

The order of the result List is not important.

- Should I divide the big List (35 million entries) into smaller blocks and iterator through them parallel? (How can I determine the perfect amount of blocks?)
- Should I start a thread for each iteration in the small List? (This will create 1500 threads and I guess a lot of them will run "parallel")

What are my other options?

Representation of the code:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Iterator<String> i = data1.iterator();i.hasNext();){ //1500 entries
  String val = i.next();
  for(Iterator<String> j = data2.iterator();j.hasNext();){ //35 million entries
    String test = j.next();
    if(val.equals(test)){
      result.add(val);
      break;
    }
  }
}
for(Iterator<String> h = result.iterator();h.hasNext();){
  //write to file
}
```

**UPDATE**

After restructuring my code and implementing the answer given by JB Nizet my application now runs a lot faster. It now only takes 20 seconds to get to the same result! Without multi-threading!

Comment: hashset for the 1500 records...so the loop up is O(1)?

Comment: how about using something more performant than a list, like a HashSet and just call `contains` on it?

Comment: Use a parallel stream

Comment: well, if you start 1k5 threads, unless you have 1k5 cores, lots of them will be racing for resources, and i don't think it will be as fast as you imagine.

Comment: Your code doesn't match your description. Where does the second data come from. Is it the same for each val? Is it a different list for each val?

Comment: Edited the code.. I indeed meant iterating through two different lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a parallel stream:

```
List<String> result = 
    data1.parallelStream()
         .filter(data2::contains)
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But since you call `contains()` on `data2` 1500 times, and since `contains()` is O(N) for a list, transforming it to a HashSet first could make things much faster: `contains()` on HashSet is O(1). You might not even need multi-threading anymore:

```
Set<String> data2Set = new HashSet<>(data2);
List<String> result = 
    data.stream()
        .filter(data2Set::contains)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Transforming List data2 to a HashSet I guess?

Comment: Well, what does my answer say? `Set<String> data2Set = new HashSet<>(data2);`.

Comment: I assume that this only works if the String in the list and in the hashset are the same objects? Or does it compare the values of the strings? Because in this case the objects in data1 and data2 are not the same (the values are read in from different csv files)

Comment: Of course not. HashSet.contains() and List.contains() both compare objects by calling equals(). And two Strings are equal if they contain the same characters in the same order. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. What is obvious for you isn't obvious for everyone ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I am also agree with your idea. What you need to do now?

> 1. First calculate number of processor in your system.
> 2. Based on number of processor split your records and create exactly that number of threads. ( numberofprocessor * 2 max, else because of context switching between thread performance will be degraded ).

Do not create unnecessarily lots of threads. That will not going to speedup your application. Check exactly how many threads you should create based on number of processor and size of memory in a system. Efficient parallel processing is depends on your machine hardware as well.